# Almost Sure Convergence and almost sure smaller than a Constant imply Convergence in Mean

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, expected-value

So my task is the following:
Consider a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $X_n \overset{a.s.}{\to} X$ and $X_n \leq B$ a.s. for $B \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $X_n \overset{\mathcal{L}^p}{\to} X$ for all $p \in \mathbb{N}$.

My ideas till now:

1. In a first step i tried to show that the expected value is bounded by both sides from zero: $0 \leq \mathbb{E}(\vert{X_n-X}\vert^p) \leq \ldots 0$ Problem here is that i would need that $\vert X_n \vert \leq B$ a.s.
2. My second attempt was to use the dominated convergence theorem. With $Y_n = B$ it follows that if $Y=B$ that $Y_n \overset{a.s.}{\to} Y$ and $\mathbb{E}(\vert Y_n - Y \vert)$. Now I also need that $\vert X_n \vert \leq Y$ and then it follows that $\mathbb{E}(\vert X_n - X \vert) \underset{n \to \infty}{\to} 0$.

Probably someone can give me a hint or another way of solving this.

Comment: This is not correct. You need $|X_n| \leq B$ instaed of $X_n \leq B$ (in which case the result is immediate from DCT.

Comment: I also thought that the instructions are not correct but if $\vert X_n \vert \leq B$ we only get $X_n \overset{\mathbb{L}^1}{\to} X$ or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_n=-nI_{(0,\frac 1 n)}, X=0, B=0,p=1$ on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure  is a counter-example.

If $|X_n| \leq B$ then $E|X_n-X|^{p} \to 0$ for all $p >0$ by DCT.

Comment: Is this $I_{(0, \frac{1}{n})}$ the characteristic function, sorry I'm not familiar with the symbol?

Comment: Yes, it is the ch. function.

Comment: @herbert123 You have  to apply DCT to the sequence $(Y_n)$ where $Y_n=|X_n-X|^{p}$.  This sequence tends to $0$ a.s. and it is bounded by $(2B)^{p}$.